# Contour plot via Scatter plot

Tags: r, plot, contour

Scatter plots are useless when number of plots is large.

So, e.g., using normal approximation, we can get the contour plot.

**My question: Is there any package to implement the contour plot from scatter plot.** 
[image]

---

Thank you @G5W !! I can do it !!

[image]

Comment: Maybe read about `geom_contour` ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply and I will try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't offer any data, so I will respond with some artificial data,
constructed at the bottom of the post. You also don't say how much data 
you have although you say it is a large number of points. I am illustrating 
with 20000 points.

You used the group number as the plotting character to indicate the group. 
I find that hard to read. But just plotting the points doesn't show the 
groups well. Coloring each group a different color is a start, but does 
not look very good.

```
plot(x,y, pch=20, col=rainbow(3)[group])
```

[image: First Attempt - color the groups]

Two tricks that can make a lot of points more understandable are:
1. Make the points transparent. The dense places will appear darker. AND
2. Reduce the point size.

```
plot(x,y, pch=20, col=rainbow(3, alpha=0.1)[group], cex=0.8)
```

[image: Transparent points of reduced size]

That looks somewhat better, but did not address your actual request. 
Your sample picture seems to show confidence ellipses. You can get 
those using the function `dataEllipse` from the `car` package.

```
library(car)
plot(x,y, pch=20, col=rainbow(3, alpha=0.1)[group], cex=0.8)
dataEllipse(x,y,factor(group), levels=c(0.70,0.85,0.95),
    plot.points=FALSE, col=rainbow(3), group.labels=NA, center.pch=FALSE)
```

[image: Plot with confidence ellipses]

But if there are really a lot of points, the points can still overlap
so much that they are just confusing. You can also use `dataEllipse` 
to create what is basically a 2D density plot without showing the points 
at all. Just plot several ellipses of different sizes over each other filling 
them with  transparent colors. The center of the distribution will appear darker. 
This can give an idea of the distribution for a very large number of points.

```
plot(x,y,pch=NA)
dataEllipse(x,y,factor(group), levels=c(seq(0.15,0.95,0.2), 0.995),
    plot.points=FALSE, col=rainbow(3), group.labels=NA, 
    center.pch=FALSE, fill=TRUE, fill.alpha=0.15, lty=1, lwd=1)
```

[image: Density plot]

You can get a more continuous look by plotting more ellipses and leaving out the border lines.

```
plot(x,y,pch=NA)
dataEllipse(x,y,factor(group), levels=seq(0.11,0.99,0.02),
    plot.points=FALSE, col=rainbow(3), group.labels=NA, 
    center.pch=FALSE, fill=TRUE, fill.alpha=0.05, lty=0)
```

[image: Smoother density plot]

Please try different combinations of these to get a nice picture of your data.

---

**Additional response to comment: Adding labels**
Perhaps the most natural place to add group labels is the centers of the
ellipses. You can get that by simply computing the centroids of the points in each group. So for example,

```
plot(x,y,pch=NA)
dataEllipse(x,y,factor(group), levels=c(seq(0.15,0.95,0.2), 0.995),
        plot.points=FALSE, col=rainbow(3), group.labels=NA,
    center.pch=FALSE, fill=TRUE, fill.alpha=0.15, lty=1, lwd=1)

## Now add labels
for(i in unique(group)) {
    text(mean(x[group==i]), mean(y[group==i]), labels=i) 
}
```

[image: Labeled Ellipses]

Note that I just used the number as the group label, but if you have a more elaborate name, you can change `labels=i` to something like
`labels=GroupNames[i]`.

---

---

**Data**

```
x = c(rnorm(2000,0,1), rnorm(7000,1,1), rnorm(11000,5,1))
twist = c(rep(0,2000),rep(-0.5,7000), rep(0.4,11000))
y = c(rnorm(2000,0,1), rnorm(7000,5,1), rnorm(11000,6,1)) + twist*x
group = c(rep(1,2000), rep(2,7000), rep(3,11000))
```

Comment: Very beautiful !! I write your code almost directly in my package. Your explanation is plain !! Your code  helps me very much !! Thank YOU !!

Comment: I want to use this contour plot in submission which do not allow using color. So,  I want to use the grouping number `1,2,3` of `group` for the scatter plot. If you  know easy code, then please let me know !!

Comment: @CamfordOxbridge A little too much for a comment. Will add to answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `hexbin::hexbin()` to show very large datasets.

@G5W gave a nice dataset:

```
x = c(rnorm(2000,0,1), rnorm(7000,1,1), rnorm(11000,5,1))
twist = c(rep(0,2000),rep(-0.5,7000), rep(0.4,11000))
y = c(rnorm(2000,0,1), rnorm(7000,5,1), rnorm(11000,6,1)) + twist*x
group = c(rep(1,2000), rep(2,7000), rep(3,11000))
```

If you don't know the group information, then the ellipses are inappropriate; this is what I'd suggest:

```
library(hexbin)
plot(hexbin(x,y))
```

which produces

[image: screenshot]

If you really want contours, you'll need a density estimate to plot.  The `MASS::kde2d()` function can produce one; see the examples in its help page for plotting a contour based on the result.  This is what it gives for this dataset:

```
library(MASS)
contour(kde2d(x,y))
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you for reply !! When I submit article, the color cannot use, so this plot  will be useful for me !! Thank you !!